# How would you make pre-written text appear when typing something?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an interactive story and I want to have the reader type something into a field, but instead of whatever they typed it types out a pre-written message. It would look something like hackertyper.net.

Comment: There's far too little information here. What field will the user type into? What pre-written messages? Where will those messages be stored? Should the user's words be replaced after a full word is completed or letter by letter? Also, what have **you** tried? We're happy to help, but you've got to come to us with some specific code and a specific question.

Comment: `keyup` event -> change `innerHTML` of a div, textarea...

Comment: @yuriy636 First, `innerHTML` is wrong (it should be `.textContent` on those elements or `.value` on most other fields). Second, please don't reward bad questions with answers.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's not even an answer, it's indications for OP to make more research and probably came with a correct question.

Comment: @yuriy636 `.innerHTML` instructs the HTML parser to parse the string for HTML. A simple replacement of a word for a word does not require HTML parsing. `.textContent` just updates the, well text content. And, the fact that it is a beginner is exactly why it's important that we provide really good answers and guidance so that bad habits aren't formed right from the start. That includes providing answers/comments to questions that aren't specific enough to answer.

Comment: I would recommend you plan how you want your project to function: Where is this pre-written text stored? What format is this pre-written text going to be held in? How do you plan to link the clients input to the next set of pre-written text to display... Once you have that planned out you should then have some source code to work with. Right now you have nothing to work with so no answer can be given.

Answer (score 0):

I use input text for this with event onkeydown="KD()" . In KD method i check which keyCode was pressed . Then e.target.value (input tag) append new chars .

Maybe will help you (build you own logic) :

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

//alert(document.body.style.backgroundColor)

function KD (e) {

    e = e || window.event
    KEY = e.keyCode || e.which
     
     // alert(KEY)
     
       switch (KEY) {
        case 65:
            e.target.value += " what a"
            break;
        case 86:
            e.target.value +=' wolf ';
            break;
        case 84:
            e.target.value +=' empty trash ';
            break;
        case 79:
            e.target.value +=' ok ';
            break;
            
    }
    
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" style="background-color:black;color:lime" onkeydown="KD()" />
```

Comment: *"Maybe will help you"*.... Explaining the source code would be more help. The OP isn't showing any existing source code so dumping this into a answer isn't going to help anyone who wishes to learn from this.

Answer (score 0):

I built a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atif_hassan/9hmmdwcg/) for your problem statement.

Basically, what I have done is write down some messages into a list and generate random indices from ***0-list.length*** which allows me to pick messages in a random fashion. I then append the message to a textarea on user's key press.

Start typing in the textarea and it will work similar to **hackertyper.net**. You can add your own messages into the list.

Here's the code.

```js
var pre_msg = ["The brown", "Fox jumped", "over the well with", "or wait", "was it a pond", "well", "that's beside the point now.", "Oh and not to forget", "HACKED !"]

function myFunction() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * pre_msg.length);
  document.getElementById("text").value +=pre_msg[index]+" ";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" style="width:300px;height:200px" value="" onkeypress="myFunction(); return false;"></textarea>
```